# How to get lines from the last match to the end of file?

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

Need to print lines after the last match to the end of file. The number of matches could be anything and not definite. I have some text as shown below.

```
MARKER
aaa
bbb
ccc
MARKER
ddd
eee
fff
MARKER
ggg
hhh
iii
MARKER
jjj
kkk
lll
```

Output desired is

```
jjj
kkk
lll
```

Do I use awk with RS and FS to get the desired output?

Comment: I have added a `grep` and a `sed` solution on top of my `awk` solution.

Comment: Is the desired output also to contain `MARKER` or just what you have shown?

Comment: @user3439894 Ideally no. But that's OK if it contains

Comment: I have edited my answer, sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: @Allan No prob. Thanks. I'm using 1st command from your answer in a perl script. Perl script interprets $0 to be the script name instead of the lines until the EOF. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: @Allan This is the line in my perl script


 "$data = \`zcat file.gz | awk -v RS='MARKER\n' 'END{printf $0}' | grep 'Data :'\`"

Comment: @Allan Nevermind. I have to escape the $0. printf \$0

Comment: Ok good that it is working!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can actually do it with `awk` (gawk) without using any pipe.

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)MARKER\n' 'END{printf "%s", $0}' file
jjj
kkk
lll
```

**Explanations:**

- You define your record separator as `(^|\n)MARKER\n` via `RS='(^|\n)MARKER\n'`, by default it is the `EOL` char
- `'END{printf "%s", $0}'` => at the end of the file, you print the whole line, as `RS` is set at `(^|\n)MARKER\n`, `$0` will include all the lines until EOF.

---

Another option is to use `grep` (GNU):

```
$ grep -zoP '(?<=MARKER\n)(?:(?!MARKER)[^\0])+\Z' file
jjj
kkk
lll
```

**Explanations:**

- `-z` to use the ASCII NUL character as delimiter
- `-o` to print only the matching
- `-P` to activate the perl mode
- PCRE regex: `(?<=MARKER\n)(?:(?!MARKER)[^\0])+\Z` explained here https://regex101.com/r/RpQBUV/2/

---

Last but not least, the following `sed` approach can also been used:

```
sed -n '/^MARKER$/{n;h;b};H;${x;p}' file
jjj
kkk
lll
```

**Explanations:**

- `n` jump to next line
- `h` replace the hold space with the current line
- `H` do the same but instead of replacing, append
- `${x;p}` at the end of the file exchange (`x`) hold space and pattern space and print (`p`)

that can be turned into:

```
tac file |  sed -n '/^MARKER$/q;p' | tac
```

if we use `tac`.

Answer (score 5):

Could you please try following.

```
tac file | awk '/MARKER/{print val;exit} {val=(val?val ORS:"")$0}' | tac
```

Benefit of this approach will be `awk` will just read last block of the Input_file(which will be actually first block for `awk` after `tac` prints it reverse)and exit after that.

***Explanation:***

```
tac file |                      ##Printing Input_file in reverse order.
awk '
  /MARKER/{                     ##Searching for a string MARKER in a line of Input_file.
    print val                   ##Printing variable val here. Because we need last occurrence of string MARKER,which has become first instance after reversing the Input_file.
    exit                        ##Using exit to exit from awk program itself.
  }
  {
    val=(val?val ORS:"")$0      ##Creating variable named val whose value will be keep appending to its own value with a new line to get values before string MARKER as per OP question.
  }
' |                             ##Sending output of awk command to tac again to make it in its actual form, since tac prints it in reverse order. 
tac                             ##Using tac to make it in correct order(lines were reversed because of previous tac).
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! Could you please explain the awk code?

Comment: @Arteezy, glad that it helped you, added full explanation to my code now, cheers.

Comment: @Arteezy: I have added a grep solution as well!

Answer (score 2):

You can try Perl as well

```
$ perl -0777 -ne ' /.*MARKER(.*)/s and print $1 ' input.txt

jjj
kkk
lll

$
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nz 's/.*MARKER.//p' file
```

This uses greed to delete all lines upto and including the last occurrence of `MARKER`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Simplest to remember:

```
tac fun.log | sed "/MARKER/Q" | tac
```

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` solution would work with any version of `awk` on any OS:

```sh
awk '/^MARKER$/ {s=""; next}  {s = s $0 RS} END {printf "%s", s}' file

jjj
kkk
lll
```