# Bash: How to get some lines from a file and save output to another file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a log file like this

```
$ cat build.log
..........
[ 60% 60917/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
[ 60% 60918/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
[ 60% 60919/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
[ 60% 60920/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
21:41:22 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (17:26 (mm:ss)) ####
```

How to generate like a new parsed logs so the output of the new file log is like this:

```
$ cat parsed.log
[ 60% 60920/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
21:41:22 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (17:26 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Like only get the last progress `[ 60% 60920/101076]` until the end of the file, using maybe grep, sed, or anything. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Already found the way using this command ```tac Build.log | sed '/^\[ /q' | tac```

Comment: @Gasiyu Then it would be great if you're post this as an answer and mark as solved ;) . It will maybe help other people this way (that the purpose of this website).

Comment: I wish people would stop putting `...`s in their examples and stick to showing representative data instead! The right answer to this question completely depends on what that first `...` line really represents - a `[...]` line or one of the other lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get lines from the last match to the end of file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334150/how-to-get-lines-from-the-last-match-to-the-end-of-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a perl:

```
$ perl -0777 -lne 'print $1 if /(^\[[^[]*\z)/m' file
```

Or a perl pipe:

```
$ perl -E 'say reverse <>' file | perl -lpE 'if (/^\[/){ say; last}' | perl -E 'say reverse <>'
```

For an `awk` you can do:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\\["}END{print "[" $0}' file
```

Of course, you may know that if the failure is always 3 lines, the simplest is just use `tail`:

```
$ tail -n 3 file
```

All print:

```
[ 60% 60920/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
21:41:22 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat build.log 
........
[ 60% 60917/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
[ 60% 60918/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
[ 60% 60919/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
[ 60% 60920/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
21:41:22 ninja failed with: exit status 1
$ awk '$2 != n[2]{print p} {p = $0; split(p,n,FS)} END{print p}' build.log
........
[ 60% 60920/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
21:41:22 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

`awk` is the right tool for this sort of thing.  Here, we check if the 2nd field matches the 2nd field of the previous line and print if it does.  Then store the previous line and repeat.  Always print the last line of the input.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\[/h;//!H;$!d;x' file
```

If a line begins `[` store it in the hold space (overwriting anything previously there).

Othewise, append the current line to the hold space.

Delete all lines except the last.

At the end of the file, swap to the hold space and print its contents.

Answer (score 0):

You sometimes doesn't got lucky if you want to perform this kind of filter without having to change the order of the lines. And if those lines aren't written at beginning of your file, or at the end: `tac`, `sort` and `uniq` would not be the right tools.

Here's a solution using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'function push(a,e) { a[length(a)+1] = e } BEGIN {split("", lines); to_replace="toreplace"; exists=0} {if ($0 ~ "^\\[ [0-9]+%"){ll=$0; if (exists <= 0) {exists++; push(lines,to_replace)}} else {push(lines, $0)}} END {for (e in lines){if (lines[e] == to_replace) {print ll} else {print lines[e]}}}' test.log 
..........
[ 60% 60920/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
21:41:22 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (17:26 (mm:ss)) ####
```

The readable and explained version:

```
# a function to append an element to an array dynamically
function push(a,e) { 
  a[length(a)+1] = e 
} 

BEGIN {
  split("", lines); # initializing an array
  to_replace="toreplace"; # you can change the replace key if you want
  exists=0
} 

{
  if ($0 ~ "^\\[ [0-9]+%"){ # matching all percentages/progression lines, regardless of their values
    ll=$0; 
    if (exists <= 0) {
      exists++; 
      push(lines, to_replace)
    }
  } else {
    push(lines, $0)
  }
}

END {
  for (e in lines) {
    if (lines[e] == to_replace) {
      print ll
    } else {
      print lines[e]
    }
  }
}
```

The difference with the [William Pursel solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759774/2900196) is when your percentages are increasing. Let's see the difference of behavior in this case:

```
$ cat test.log 
..........
[ 60% 60917/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
[ 60% 60918/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
[ 60% 60919/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
[ 61% 60920/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
21:41:22 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (17:26 (mm:ss)) ####
$ awk 'function push(a,e) { a[length(a)+1] = e } BEGIN {split("", lines); to_replace="toreplace"; exists=0} {if ($0 ~ "^\\[ [0-9]+%"){ll=$0; if (exists <= 0) {exists++; push(lines,to_replace)}} else {push(lines, $0)}} END {for (e in lines){if (lines[e] == to_replace) {print ll} else {print lines[e]}}}' test.log 
..........
[ 61% 60920/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
21:41:22 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (17:26 (mm:ss)) ####
$ awk '$2 != n[2]{print p} {p = $0; split(p,n,FS)} END{print p}' test.log 
..........
[ 60% 60919/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
[ 61% 60920/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
21:41:22 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (17:26 (mm:ss)) ####
```

So you might wanna choose either if you only want to keep the last progression line even if percentage aren't the same or if you only want to filter the lines that have the same percentage multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If it's guaranteed that the first line you want to ouput it's the last line beginning with `[`, then you can do this, which essentially replaces everything from the beginning of the file to the last `[` preceded by a linebreak with a single `[`:

```sh
sed -z 's/.*\n\[/[/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `...` line at the start of your sample input represents more leading `[...] ...` lines:

```
$ awk '/^\[/{p=$0 ORS; next} {print p $0; p=""}' build.log
[ 60% 60920/101076] AAPT2 compile ....
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
21:41:22 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (17:26 (mm:ss)) ####
```

If that assumption is wrong then please edit your question to show a minimal, **complete**, verifiable example - one with only representative values, not `...`s.